How can I set specific conditions for a calculated column in R?
i have this table:
aux_nov <- hist[, c("contrato", "importe", "mob", "fecha_pago", "dias_atraso")]

with this values in this columns, so...
contrato <- c(598047, 598047, 598047, 598047, 598047, 598047, 598047, 598047)
fecha_pago <- c(2023-10-21, NA, NA, NA, 2024-03-13, 2024-04-02, NA, NA)
seguimiento_mes <- c(2023-11-30, 2023-11-30, 2023-11-30, 2023-11-30, 2023-11-30, 2023-11-30, 2023-11-30, 2023-11-30)

I want this conditions:
If fecha_pago is NA then we check the previous date and if it is NA then it remains NA,
if the previous date is not NA then we see if that fecha_pago > seguimiento_mes then previous fecha_pago is placed, if fecha_pago < seguimiento_mes then NA
I have not been able to create these conditions for my payment_date column, I have tried with a buble but it gives me values ​​that I am not looking for or it does not make any changes.
for example i try something like this:
last_valid_payment_date <- NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(aux_nov)) {
  if (is.na(aux_nov$fecha_pago[i])) {
    if (!is.na(last_valid_payment_date)) {
      if (last_valid_payment_date > aux_nov$seguimiento_mes[i]) {
        aux_nov$fecha_pago[i] <- last_valid_payment_date
      } else {
        aux_nov$fecha_pago[i] <- NA
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (aux_nov$fecha_pago[i] > aux_nov$seguimiento_mes[i]) {
      last_valid_payment_date <- aux_nov$fecha_pago[i]
    }
  }
}

but this code does not group me by id, so in the saved date it can save the other id's so it can bring me wrong information.
This is the result that i want:



contrato
fecha_pago
seguimiento_mes




598047
2023-10-21
2023-11-30


598047
NA
2023-11-30


598047
NA
2023-11-30


598047
NA
2023-11-30


598047
2024-03-13
2023-11-30


598047
2024-03-13
2023-11-30


598047
2024-03-13
2023-11-30


598047
2024-03-13
2023-11-30




Update based on OP's comments
This solution assumes:

contrato is your ID column
retain values where fecha_pago < seguimiento_mes
repeat first fecha_pago value that is > seguimiento_mes until end of group regardless of subsequent values

I have modified your sample dataset slightly to demonstrate that it works.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create sample df
contrato <- c(598047, 598047, 598047, 598047, 598047, 598047, 598047, 598047)
fecha_pago <- as.Date(c("2023-10-21", NA, NA, NA, "2024-03-13", "2024-04-02", "2024-05-02", NA))
seguimiento_mes <- as.Date(c("2023-11-30", "2023-11-30", "2023-11-30", "2023-11-30",
                             "2023-11-30", "2023-11-30", "2023-11-30", "2023-11-30"))

aux_nov <- data.frame(contrato, fecha_pago, seguimiento_mes)

# Group df by contrato, apply criteria
aux_nov |>
  group_by(contrato) |>
  mutate(temp = if_else(!is.na(lag(fecha_pago)) & 
                          fecha_pago > seguimiento_mes &
                          fecha_pago != lag(fecha_pago),
                        NA, fecha_pago),
         temp = if_else(!is.na(temp) & temp > seguimiento_mes, temp, NA)) |>
  fill(temp, .direction = "down") |>
  mutate(fecha_pago = if_else(!is.na(temp), temp, fecha_pago)) |>
  select(-temp) |>
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#   contrato fecha_pago seguimiento_mes
#      <dbl> <date>     <date>
# 1   598047 2023-10-21 2023-11-30
# 2   598047 NA         2023-11-30
# 3   598047 NA         2023-11-30
# 4   598047 NA         2023-11-30
# 5   598047 2024-03-13 2023-11-30
# 6   598047 2024-03-13 2023-11-30
# 7   598047 2024-03-13 2023-11-30
# 8   598047 2024-03-13 2023-11-30


What I want to achieve is that in this example if when going through the rows I come across a payment date "2024-03-13" in this case where
2024-03-13 > monitoring_month = 2023-11-30 then from the row that appears the payment date 2024-03-13 downwards, enter the value of that payment date, which in this case would be 2024-03- 13

The result I am looking for is that "2024-03-13" appears in the fecha_pago column starting from row 5

@BrianGarciaAlvarez - please add an example of the result you are expecting to your question (similar to the result I added to my answer). This will make it easier to help you.

@L Tyrone i already edited my post to show what is the result that i want, thanks
